# Gerar arquivo CSV de tabela HTML via JavaScript com UFT-8

Tags: javascript, csv

Quero exportar uma lista de produtos de uma para CSV de uma tabela HTML via javascript. Até aí tudo bem, mas quando gero o arquivo sempre vem com os caracteres de acentuações deformado. Alguém pode me ajudar e dizer o que tá faltando para os arquivos virem com a acentuação uft-8 correta? Estou usando a meta uft-8  na header da pagina.

```js
function tableToCSV() {

 // Variável para armazenar os dados csv finais
 var csv_data = [];

 // Obtém os dados de cada linha
 var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

     // Obtém os dados de cada coluna
     var cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td,th');

     // Armazena cada dado de linha csv
     var csvrow = [];
     for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

         // Obtém os dados de texto de cada célula
         // de uma linha e envia para csvrow
         csvrow.push(cols[j].innerHTML);
     }

     // Combina cada valor de coluna com vírgula
     csv_data.push(csvrow.join(";"));
 }

 // Combina os dados de cada linha com o novo caractere de linha
 csv_data = csv_data.join('\n');

 // Chama esta função para baixar o arquivo csv
 downloadCSVFile(csv_data);

}

function downloadCSVFile(csv_data) {

 // Cria objeto de arquivo CSV e feed
 // nosso csv_data nele
 CSVFile = new Blob([csv_data], {
     type: "text/csv"
 });

 // Cria um link temporário para iniciar
 // processo de download
 var temp_link = document.createElement('a');

 //Baixa o arquivo csv
 temp_link.download = "produtos.csv";
 var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(CSVFile);
 temp_link.href = url;

 // Este link não deve ser exibido
 temp_link.style.display = "none";
 document.body.appendChild(temp_link);

 //Clique automaticamente no link para
 // aciona o download
 temp_link.click();
 document.body.removeChild(temp_link);
}
```

```html
 <button type="button" onclick="tableToCSV()">BAIXAR ARQUIVO CSV</button>
 <br/>
 <br/>
<table class="uk-table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>Active (0/1)</th>
                <th>Name *</th>
                <th>Categories (x,y,z...)</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Água, Telefone, Relógios</td>
                <td>Tênis, Calçados, Sapato</td>
                <td>Valores</td>
                <td>Preços</td>
            </tr>
                <?php } ?>
         </table>
        <br/>
        <br/>
```

Comment: Poderia verificar a existência do cabeçalho HTTP Content-Type e caso exista poderia postar o conteúdo.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione "\ufeff" antes de `csv_data` na instanciação do Blob:

```js
CSVFile = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv_data], {
    type: "text/csv"
});
```

Essa string representa um [BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) e "força" o arquivo a abrir corretamente.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.